# ParseQuery include doesn't work

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

here is my code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Photo");
    query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    query.setLimit(1000);
    //query.include("mission");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> photosParseList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to get all my photo objects with related "mission" object. (Every photo have pointer to table Mission, column name "mission"). I can do this with subquery, but i want to get it with single query using include. When I use

```
query.include("mission");
```

it excludes "mission" from result. If i don't use this line i can get "mission" object from result, but without needed columns.

Comment: The code you provided (with the include statement)  should contain all the simple types of mission e.g. `photos.get(0).getParseObject("mission").getString("name")` to get the name of the first photo's mission

Comment: Should, but not contains "mission" object. photos.get(0)..getParseObject("mission") returns null.

Comment: And you verified that the data browser on Parse correctly shows that a pointer exists on the "mission"  column

Comment: Yes, if i don't use include i can get "mission" object like photos.get(0).getParseObject("mission") but it will have no data

Comment: Sounds strange, I still suspect that it so happens that the first photo simply does not have a mission set. That matches the behavior you describe.

Comment: try  to add condition `query.whereExists("mission");` with your include statement. This will fetch only that record which have not null mission object.

Comment: ved, cYrixmorten, thank you.  query.whereExists("mission") works.